# A client connected to two servers with the same port

Tags: linux, tcp, port

According to TCP/IP specification I consider it impossible to ESTABLISH two connections with the same port from the client side. BUT IT DIT!

[image: problem]

The matchine 172.22.3.137 acts as client and left ones are servers. So does this mean it is possible for a client to connect to multiple servers with identical port?

**Any ideas?**

Comment: There's no evidence here that the connections were active at the same time.

Comment: But I've dump the connections with "tcpdump" command and found it really active. There are even data flows~

Answer (score 1):

According to the TCP specification, a connection is identified by four numbers: client port, client address, server port, server address.

It is entirely possible for client ports to be reused, otherwise you could have only 64k connections from any machine.

What is not possible, is to connect from the same client port to the same server (address and port), this would make the two connections indistinguishable.

Comment: Trying to understand your answer - Does it mean, that one client can use same port to connect(send and receive) data from different peers (with 2 sets of different set of pairs of ipaddr and ports). As this seems to be the case in the OP log/image shown.

Comment: @JanWrobel Can you write down a Java snippet to reproduce this issue? PS: our application runs on Java.

Comment: @Selfer You appear to have 'reproduced this issue' yourself. Why do you need another example?

Comment: @Sefler This isn't Java specific behavior, client (ephemeral) ports are assigned by operating system. You can run any TCP client to establish thousands of connections with two different servers and you will see client ports duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that when second connection was setuo first one still exist ??

Check am sure first one must have terminated as if not then your machine willnot send any ack and three way handshake will not complete.

Comment: You mean I should try to terminate one connection from the server side and check whether the FIN-ACK can be received?

Comment: yes you can try that

but first check whether both connection are active on same time say be sending and receiving data

Comment: The clients and servers belong to different clusters and there IS a Load Balance called F5 acts as a gateway.